# Using a ternary operator inside of a preprocessor

Tags: c

I've just started learning C and I need some help with understanding macrocommands. I wanted to create one which calculates the maximum between two numbers.

I know the names are not chosen quite well, but it is just for testing purposes.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max(a, b) (int max2, a>=b ? max2 = a : max2 = b)

void main()
{
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    int maximum = max(a, b);
    printf("%d", maximum);
}
```

I'm getting an error on line 8, (the one with int maximum = max(a, b) ) saying "expected a ')'".

I guess that's because I'm using the preprocessor wrong (in my opinion), but I don't know how I should do it properly in this case.

Can anybody help me understand what am I doing wrong and how I should use preprocessors? Thanks.

[image: photo]

Comment: In cases like this it's useful to view the output of the preprocessor before the file is compiled. If you don't yet have a way of doing it, you absolutely should.

Comment: I added a screenshot into my post. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean view the while file (well specifically the breaking line) after it's preprocessed.

Comment: Why not just use `((a >= b) ? a : b)`?

Comment: (with parentheses).

Comment: `(int max2, ...)` is not a valid expression. You can't have variable declarations in the middle of an expression in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you understand how a macro works; you don't declare a new variable `max2` inside it. The preprocessor is a simple text substitution system.

Your macro expands to:

```
int maximum = (int max2, a>=b ? max2 = a : max2 = b);
```

This is a syntax error. A `max` macro is very simple, all you need is:

```
#define max(a, b) ((a) >= (b)) ? (a) : (b)
```

This will then expand to:

```
int maximum = ((a) >= (b)) ? (a) : (b);
```

Which will give you the result you want.

Comment: Why did you use so many paranthesis? Couldn't it be only #define max(a, b) ((a > b) ? a : b) ?

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu Read this article: https://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/12/17/macros-why-theyre-evil

Comment: I will. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Re "*Couldn't it be only `#define max(a, b) ((a > b) ? a : b)`?*", No Consider `max(c & 1, d & 1)` and the fact that `>` as higher precedence than `&`.

Answer (score 3):

What you have written, comes down to:

```
int maximum = (int max2, a>=b ? max2 = a : max2 = b); // this looks weird (what's that max2 for?)
```

Why don't you simply write the following:

```
#define max(a, b) ((a)>=(b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Like this, your line of code becomes:

```
int maximum = ((a)>=(b) ? (a) : (b));
```

Which looks a lot more logical. (Briefly, you don't need `max2`)

Comment: I thought it works like a function, but I just have to define it in other way (with #define). Yes, you're right, I don't need max2. But why did you both use so many paranthesis? Couldn't I use only #define max(a, b) ((a > b) ? a : b) ?

Comment: For the parentheses: imagine you write `#define mul(a,b) (a*b)`, and you do `mul(1+2,3)`, then you will get `1+2*3`, which is 7, while you want `(1+2)*3`, which is 9. You are right, the parentheses might not be needed here (in the `max` case), but it's good habit.

Comment: The arguments to a macro may be complex expressions, which could mess up the operator precedence within the macro. Putting parentheses around each parameter makes them more self-contained.

Comment: @Octavian Niculescu, `max(c & 1, d & 1)` would fail with `#define max (a>=b ? a : b)` cause `(c & 1>=d & 1 ? c & 1 : d & 1)` is equivalent to `(c & (1>=d) & 1 ? c & 1 : d & 1)`

Comment: @Octavian Niculescu, This brings up another points. We conventionally use uppercase letters for macros to signal they are macros. Cause doing `max(expensive_func(), func_with_side_effects())` would be bad